# How to force a docker container in IBM Bluemix to connect a volume?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

is there any way to refuse to start a container where there is no volume connected to certain path?

I have a mysql container and want to block starting the container (exit with an error) where there is no volume connected to /var/lib/mysql to host volume. There is an option in IBM Bluemix for adding a volume to the container with the container's specified path. I need to prevent starting the container if someone forget to add the volume.

Alternatively, is it possible to find out if there is a volume from the host to the container from inside the container? (Adding a check to the entrypoint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container volumes contain the name of the container in the mount path, so basically you can create an entry point script in your `Dockerfile` that checks for the presence of the volume name. I used `df | grep volume-name` to check if volume is mounted in the entry point script.
This is an example of running `df` on container with volume mounted (volume here is adsdatabase):

```
# df
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-8:16-212573961-302136b327f5923d7c9b8c6c2cf62c0783 10190136 466892 9182572 5% /
tmpfs 132022832 0 132022832 0% /dev
shm 65536 0 65536 0% /dev/shm
nfsdal0901d.service.softlayer.com:/IBM01SV531277_366/adsdatabase 20971520 23168 20948352 1% /data
/dev/sdb 11522552336 200321280 10741487072 2% /etc/hosts
udev 132009268 4 132009264 1% /dev/tty
```

I recommend you don't use a common name, like "data", for the volume name or the grep would match that.

Here are the steps I did:

1. Create an entry point script that checks for the presence of the volume using `df` command (see sample `entrypoint.sh` file below)
2. Create a `Dockerfile` and add `ENTRYPOINT` command to run your entry point script (see sample `Dockerfile` file below)
3. Create a new image and push to your Bluemix registry, for example:

   `$ docker build -t ads-volumesample .
    $ docker tag ads-volumesample registry.ng.bluemix.net/namespace/ads-volumesample
    $ docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/namespace/ads-volumesample`
4. Create a volume - the name of the volume matches the check in the entry point script, for example:

   `$ cf ic volume create adsdatabase`
5. Create a new container and add the new volume:

   `$ cf ic run -v adsdatabase:/data --name ads-volumesample1 registry.ng.bluemix.net/namespace/ads-volumesample`

If you do not add the volume when creating the container, the container will fail and will automatically shutdown in a few minutes.

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if df | grep adsdatabase > /dev/null; then
   echo "Found volume"
else
   echo "Volume not found"
   exit 1
fi

exec "$@"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode

ADD ./app /node

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN cd /node && npm install
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "/node/app.js"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I already did it this way before you wrote that. The problem was, I was at first trying it locally with only Docker. But with bluemix you can get the volume. More than df, I recommend mount | grep nfs4.

Comment: Using nfs4 you will depending from the technology, theorically it could change transparently and your script won't script. Use the volume name like suggested by Alex, it is really more portable

Comment: I don't care about the volume name. I care about having whatever volume connected to the /var/lib/mysql inside the container...

Answer (score 1):

You could simply run a script that checks if the path where the volume should be mounted (/var/lib/mysql in your case) is containing the volume content (it confirms that the volume is correctly mounted)
Keep in mind that:
- the volume mount path exists even when the volume is not mounted, you must check its content and not the path itself
- if you run an initialisation process the first time you start the volume you could expect that in that moment the volume is empty and the mount point is empty too: so skip the check when initialising, or have a specific case for this

Comment: How can I check from INSIDE the container something that is completely outside the container?

Comment: Or do you mean like having something in the connected volume first? And then the starting container checks if it is there?

Comment: exactly.
You could check for a mounted filesystem, and Bluemix volumes are mounted through NFS, but it isn't really portable.
So what you could have more portable is checking the content of the volume mount point, when it is expected to be initialised (database created and data inserted): this means that when your container is starting will check the path /var/lib/mysql (if it is the volume mount point) and if empty (so the volume hasn't been attached to the container) will not start the mysql database

Comment: That is actually more work (I would need an admin to force him to create volumes and uploading something in them or making a script for it) than just forcing the dev TO CHECK if he did not forget to connect the volume. The accepted answer above is much better solution.

Comment: Checking the mounted device is one of the steps I would run. The second step should be the mounted path content: your volume could be empty, so you should check for the content.